# Relations in a space generated by indicator functions

Tags: linear-algebra

**Simple Question**

I ran into the following seemingly simple question.

For an arbitrary set $M$ consider the real vector space generated by indicator functions $\chi_A$ of all subsets $A\subset M$. (The space of functions with finitely many distinct values.) What is the space of relations with respect to the generators?

More specifically, is it true that relations of the form $$\chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_{A\cup B}-\chi_{A\cap B}=0$$ generate this space of relations? This set of relations is linearly dependent, is there some reasonable way of narrowing it further? What is the situation over other fields?

**Additional Question**

We may then restrict our attention to a distinguished set $\Omega\subset 2^M$ of subsets and the space generated by their indicators. Sometimes it turns out that the space of their relations is generated by relations of the above form for which $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are both in $\Omega$.

Might there exist a fairly general sufficient condition under which $\Omega$ has this property? For example a condition which will allow to replicate the proof of the above for $\Omega$. That is, if the above holds.

(If I'm not confusing anything, compact convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and convex polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have this property, although the proofs are nontrivial. And this is where I'm coming from, but I'm actually hoping that any sort of geometry will have fairly little to do with all this.)

**Update. As Emil Jeřábek points out below, the first question is not that interesting. As for the second one, further consideration has led me to believe that the corresponding statements for convex compacts and for convex polyhedra are, in fact, very geometric in nature. (For convex compacts the space of relations is actually generated by all the inclusion-exclusion formulas with convex union rather than the above.) I don't really know if there's much left to discuss here.**

Comment: What about all the other relations that arise from the inclusion-exclusion principle; these generalize the 2-subset formula you gave? Or does the formula for two subsets yield all the others? [Edit: It does appear to, which makes this comment irrelevant, but I don't know how remove it.]

Comment: The given relations do not suffice, as they do not generate $\chi_{\emptyset}=0$. However, this is the only obstacle: the space is generated by the relations $\chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_{A\cup B}=0$ for disjoint $A,B$. To see this, use these relations to rewrite any linear combination of characteristic functions as a linear combination of $\chi_{A_i}$ for nonempty pairwise disjoint $A_i$; the latter are linearly independent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yep, right you are! Just recognized that as well. So the first part of the question is silly after all...

Comment: These relation are still linearly dependent though. Any chance of narrowing it down to a basis?